# TypeError: user.updateProfile is not a function in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

Im trying to  add the display name for firebase createUserWithEmailAndPassword auth. but getting:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: user.updateProfile is not a function

```
const User = createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
             .then((userCredentials) => {
                  const user = userCredentials.user;
                  user.updateProfile({displayName : 'John'})
             })
                
console.log(User);
```

Comment: Looks like you're following an out-of-date guide. There is no `updateProfile()` method on the [User](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.user.md#user_interface) interface